# Setting a DevOps task drop down option from a variable

Tags: google-play, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am writing a release pipeline to upload an apk (installer) to Google Play. I am using the Google Play - Release task to do this. This is in a classic pipeline (our code is in TFS.)
One of the options is the Track to upload the apk to. The options are:

[image: Track options]

I want to set this option based on a variable that is set in one of the previous tasks. I have a previous task that sets the release.task variable to either Internal test or Production based on whether it is a public release or not. I am using it in the Google Play task like this:

[image: Use of variable]

However when I run the pipeline it does not recognise the value, even though it is one of the valid options:

[image: Error]

Is there a way to get around this? I need to control which track the pipeline writes to based on a value in our code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue with this scenario - you can set the value from a variable but the values are different (for this task) from those on display in the UI. For the two tracks I am using the values are:

Production -> production (note the difference in the case)

Internal test -> internal